# TF14098 Access Denied Branch in TFS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, branching-and-merging, user-permissions

I've got some developers who shouldn't get Admin access to a team collection or the project so they're not deleting the code.

However they need to be able to branch.

We recently upgraded to TFS 2013 and VS 2013 for all of our projects and the developers are receiving this error message:

[image]

I've looked for previous solutions but the directions don't seem to map to the interface for TFS/VS 2013.

How can I grant them the permissions the need for branching?

Thanks

Edit: Adding this screenshot to show where exactly the setting is in the web interface.
[image: TFS Settings for Version Control]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set them under the `Control Panel/<Project>/<TeamName>/Version Control`.
There you can set the permission "Branch creation" (for git, "ManageBranch" in TVC) and the oders you read in the error Window.

For additional information read the following link: [Team Foundation Server permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx#VersionControl)

Comment: Is it not possible to do this at a collection level?  I always want my "Senior Developers" group to have be allowed to Branch/Merge on any project they have access too.

Answer (score 0):

For me funny thing was; I accidentally selected wrong work-space / user. It took almost a couple of hours to trace it. It was giving me same error as above, Once I have selected correct `workspace` it worked for me.

[image: Work Space]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tfs by administrator user.

Select Project Settings > Repositories > YOURPROJECT Team > Lock

Set **Lock** option to **Allow**

[image]